# Jetpack Compose Scaffold + Modal Bottom Sheet

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-scaffold

I'm trying to design a layout using Compose that consists of:

1. TopAppBar
2. Body (content)
3. BottomAppBar
4. A Bottom Sheet that represents a menu when clicked (Modal Bottom Sheet)

-------TopAppBar-------

------MainContent------

------BottomAppBar-----

----ModalBottomSheet---

Compose offers 3 components:

1. Scaffold
2. BottomSheetScaffold
3. ModalBottomSheetLayout

**Scaffold** has no bottom sheet property

**BottomSheetScaffold** has no BottomAppBar property

**ModalBottomSheetLayout** has only content and sheetContent

`Which of these components should I combine and in what **structure** to achieve what I want?`

```kotlin
Scaffold(
  topBar = { TopBar() },
  content = { innerPadding -> Body(innerPadding) },
  bottomAppbar = { BottomAppBar() }
)
ModalBottomSheetLayout(
  sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(
    initialValue = ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden
  ),
  sheetContent = { SheetContent() },
)
BottomSheetScaffold(
  scaffoldState = ...,
  sheetContent = { SheetContent() },
  content = { ScreenContent() },
)
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
val bottomState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden)
ModalBottomSheetLayout(
    sheetState = bottomState,
    sheetContent = {
        //. sheetContent
    }
) {
    Scaffold(
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                title = {
                    Text(text = "TopAppBar")
                }
            )
        },
        bottomBar = {
            BottomAppBar(modifier = Modifier) {
                IconButton(
                    onClick = {
                        coroutineScope.launch { bottomState.show() }  
                    }
                ) {
                    Icon(Icons.Filled.Menu, contentDescription = "Localized description")
                }
            }
        },

        content = { innerPadding ->
            //...main content
        }
    )
}
```

[image]

Comment: We can combine bottomSheetState and drawerState with rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState. How can we do the same with rememberModalBottomSheetState, so that we have both modalBottomSheet and drawer?