# How can I implement Bottom sheet with BottomBar in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-list, jetpack-compose-navigation, android-jetpack-compose-scaffold

So what I am trying to achieve is:

- A home composable that hosts a BottomNav Bar (Scaffold is used here )
- Bottom Nav Bar is attached with 3 other composables
- Each of the 3 composables has its own lazy column
- Every item in the 3 lazy columns have a menu icon which when clicked opens the bottom sheet

I was able to achieve the above by enclosing the scaffold inside a ModalBottonSheetLayout with the help of this answer here: [Jetpack Compose Scaffold + Modal Bottom Sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67744381/jetpack-compose-scaffold-modal-bottom-sheet)

The issue:

- The purpose of the bottom sheet is to show a menu item which when clicked should  delete the item from the lazyColumn
- so the bottom sheet needs to know the details of the item that was clicked to delete it

How can I achieve that?
The home composable does not have any information about the items inside the lazy columns present in the composables that it hosts.

Is there a different way to approach this?

Here is my code:

HomeComposable.kt

```
fun HomeComposable(homeViewModel: HomeViewModel, 
     navController: NavHostController) {
        ModalBottomSheetLayout(
           sheetContent = {
           //get the id of the message here so it can be     
           //deleted
               Button(
                   text = "delete Message")
                   onClick = deleteMessage(message.id
               )
           }
) {
    Scaffold(
    content = {
    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = 
    WHATS_NEW_COMPOSABLE) {

          composable(MESSAGES_COMPOSABLE) {
            MessageItemsComposable(
                homeViewModel,
                navController,
                bottomSheetState
            )
          }
 
    }
  }  
)
```

MessageItemsComposable.kt

```
val messages : List<Messages> = getMessagesFromNetwork()

LazyColumn {
    items(messages) { message ->
    Row{
        Text(message.title)
        Icon(
            onClick = {
             bottomState.show()
             //show a bottom sheet with an option to delete                 
            }
        ) {

           //Draw the icon
           }
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you attach the code ?

Comment: Hi @StefanoSansone, i have updated the question with my code

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: @vn1gam Yes I was able to solve it, the solution was quite a complex one though... So here is what I did:
- Create a mutable variable in the NavGraph that holds the current value of the menu item clicked in one of the items clicked in the Lazy Columns(it will be a dummy value when initialized)
- Pass this variable as a parameter to the respective composables
- populate this value when the menu item was clicked in the LC
- Now the NavGraph has the correct value populated in the variable
- The bottom sheet can now show a menu and perform logic for this specific item

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

For that case, I would use a repository with a StateFlow. This repository would be a singleton and it's responsible of maintaining data and deleting them. Your composable list will listen to state changes and your bottomsheet will call delete() to delete the selected element.

```
class Repository<T> {
    private val _state = MutableStateFlow<T>(initialState)
    val state: StateFlow<T> = _state

    fun delete(data: T) {
        _state.remove(data)
    }
}
```

The parent of you composable list should provide a callback. This callback should be invoked when the user clicks on a list item and that item is passed as parameter.

```
@Composable
fun DataList(onItemClick(item: T)) {
    // list implementation with onItemCkick as onClick callback
}
```

When invoked, you can open the bottomsheet and pass the item to it.

Comment: Hi, i need your help, and this is what i'm searching for.
I have 8 button and 1 bottomSheet, how can i change the texte of a button when i'm clicking a text in bottomSheet.
The issue is that the bottomSheet doesn't know whick button was clicked

Comment: Hi, 
I think it is better to open a question to have more context. But from what I understand, you must pass a callback to the bottom sheet to notify the button with the new text and eventually a list a text to show in the bottom sheet. Based on the button clicked, you invoke the bottom sheet with different callback and text list.